# How to print a Pandas dataframe to Latex without the index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, latex

### Setup

I have an example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A':[1,2],'B':[3,4]})
```

---

### What I did

Using [to_latex()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html), I can print this dataframe to a latex table. However, I do not want the index column to be included. The `index_names` keyword should help. According to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html):

> **index_names :** ***bool, default True***
>
> Prints the names of the indexes.

I do:

```
df.to_latex(index_names=False)
```

---

### What I got

```
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\toprule
{} &  A &  B \\
\midrule
0 &  1 &  3 \\
1 &  2 &  4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

This does not match expectation: the 0 and the 1 should not be there, at the beginning of the two lines (between `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`). I also try `df.to_latex()`, which gives the same output as I had before.

---

### The question

It seems that setting `index_names=False` does not have any effect on the output. [Link to a Google Colab notebook confirming this result](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QvegMFcorQzLu04CQbgD518AqZIKznWn?usp=sharing).

**How can I print out a Pandas dataframe without the index column?**

Comment: Use `index=False`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `index=False`, not `index_names=False`:

```
>>> df.to_latex(index=False)
'\\begin{tabular}{rr}\n\\toprule\n A &  B \\\\\n\\midrule\n 1 &  3 \\\\\n 2 &  4 \\\\\n\\bottomrule\n\\end{tabular}\n'
```

What `index_names=False` does is remove the line beneath the column headers that contains the name of the index levels. This only happens when there *is* an index name. See the lines with `idx` below:

```
>>> df.rename_axis('idx')
     A  B
idx      
0    1  3
1    2  4
>>> df.rename_axis('idx').to_latex()
'\\begin{tabular}{lrr}\n\\toprule\n{} &  A &  B \\\\\nidx &    &    \\\\\n\\midrule\n0   &  1 &  3 \\\\\n1   &  2 &  4 \\\\\n\\bottomrule\n\\end{tabular}\n'
>>> df.rename_axis('idx').to_latex(index_names=False)
'\\begin{tabular}{lrr}\n\\toprule\n{} &  A &  B \\\\\n\\midrule\n0 &  1 &  3 \\\\\n1 &  2 &  4 \\\\\n\\bottomrule\n\\end{tabular}\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

New interface of `pandas` uses `styler`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})
df.style.format(
    formatter="{:.2f}".format).format_index(
    axis=1, formatter="${}$".format).hide(
    axis=0).to_latex(
    buf="latex.tex")
```